# TFS 2012 Update 1 - Compressed Index Error During Update

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I just attempted installing Update 1 on our TFS 2012 server. The installation made me run back through the configuration wizard. I received the below error during the upgrade of our primary project collection:

> [Error] The index 'PK_WorkItemsAre_Sparse' could not be created or rebuilt. A compressed index is not supported on table that contains sparse columns or a column set column.

In speaking with our DBA, he sees that the upgrade dropped the PK for the table, so it looks like the process is trying to recreate the PK and receiving this error. The rest of the update finished and now I am left with a project collection that is offline and will not complete the servicing job that is queued up for it.

What should I do next?

Comment: Can you send me your log file for the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you tried re-running the services step from the Admin Console

2) restore all of your databases to the backup that you created before you ran the upgrade. That will get you working now...

Then check:

1. Does the account you are logged in as have SysAdmin for the Database Server (required)
2. Does the TFS Service Account as have SysAdmin for the Database Server (required)

If this is the case we need to look at the actual error in the logs. I have found in a couple of cases with separate SQL server where a network communication error has glitched the upgrade.

- [TFS 2012 Update 1 – TF255430: the database was partially upgraded during a failed upgrade](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-2012-update-1-tf255430-the-database-was-partially-upgraded-during-a-failed-upgrade/)

This may help and if it is the cause will allow you to run the upgrade again and not get the same error.

3) Burn a support call with Microsoft (you get 3 with your MSDN and more with your enterprise agreement)